# How can I change implementation from 3 variables of time (hours, minutes, seconds) into a single variable consisting of only seconds?

Tags: java, arrays, string, constructor, int

Right now I have 3 variables storing time (hours, minutes, seconds) and I have constructors and getters that correspond to these variables. I am very confused as to how I should go about using a single int variable to store the total number of seconds in place of the hours, minutes, and seconds variables. Can anybody help me start off? I'm mainly confused about the rearranging of the constructors and getters in order to execute properly with a single variable (seconds). I hope what I am requesting is clear, I just need a push in the right direction, thank you so much.

```
public class Relay 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       TimeB[] raceLegs = new TimeB[3];
       raceLegs[0] = new TimeB(903);
       raceLegs[1] = new TimeB(0,1,43);
       raceLegs[2] = new TimeB(0,45,17);

       System.out.println("First runner:  " + raceLegs[0].toString());
       System.out.println("Second runner: " + raceLegs[1].toString());
       System.out.println("Third runner:  " + raceLegs[2].toString());

       raceLegs[0].add( raceLegs[1] );
       raceLegs[0].add( raceLegs[2] );

       System.out.println("The Sum of all runners is:  " + raceLegs[0].toString());

    }


}       


public class TimeB implements Time {

    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    private int seconds;
    private int totalSeconds;

    /**
     * Simple constructor assumes data is in proper format
     * 
     * @param h - number of hours
     * @param m - number of minutes
     * @param s - number of seconds
     */
    public TimeB(int h, int m, int s) {
        hours = h;
        minutes = m;
        seconds = s;


    }

//formula to calculate total sum of runners
    public void addTime(TimeB other) {
        this.hours += other.hours;
        this.minutes += other.minutes;
        this.seconds += other.seconds;
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of leftover seconds (those not part of a full minute)
     * in this object
     * 
     * @return the number of seconds
     */
    public int getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of leftover minutes (those not part of a full hour) in
     * this object
     * 
     * @return the number of minutes
     */
    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of full hours in this object
     * 
     * @return the number of hours
     */
    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor that assumes a total number of seconds
     * 
     * @param total - the total number of seconds taken
     */
//  public TimeB(int total) {
//      hours = total / 3600;
//      minutes = (total / 60) % 60;
//      seconds = total % 60;
//  }

    public TimeB(int total) {
    hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
    minutes = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    }
    /**
     * Adds the given time to the current time, producing the sum
     * 
     * @param other - the given time to add
     * @return the sum of this time and the other time
     */
    public Time add(Time other) {
        int remainder = 0;
        int newSec = this.seconds + other.getSeconds();

        // if over a minute, carry.
        if (newSec >= 60) {
            remainder = 1;
            newSec -= 60;
        }
        this.seconds = newSec;
        int newMin = this.minutes + remainder + other.getMinutes();
        remainder = 0;

        // carry if over an hour
        if (newMin >= 60) {
            remainder = 1;
            newMin -= 60;
        }
        this.minutes = newMin;
        this.hours += other.getHours() + remainder;

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Return a String representation of this time
     * 
     * @return this time represented as a String in hh:mm:ss format
     */
//  public String toString() {
//      return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
//
//       return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
//  }

    public String toString() {
    return String.format("%02d",seconds);
    }

    public int compareTo(Time other) {
        return 17;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor that initializes TimeA object in string format
     * @param t
     */
    public TimeB(String t) {
        hours = Integer.parseInt(t.substring(0,t.indexOf(':')));
        minutes = Integer.parseInt(t.substring(t.indexOf(':') + 1,t.lastIndexOf(':')));
        seconds = Integer.parseInt(t.substring(t.lastIndexOf(':') + 1,t.length()));

    }

}



public interface Time extends Comparable<Time> {

    /**
     * Return the number of leftover seconds (those not part of a full minute) 
     *      in this object
     * @return the number of seconds
     */
    public int getSeconds();

    /**
     * Return the number of leftover minutes (those not part of a full hour) 
     *      in this object
     * @return the number of minutes
     */
    public int getMinutes();

    /**
     * Return the number of full hours in this object
     * @return the number of hours
     */
    public int getHours();

    /**
     * Return a String representation of this object in hh:mm:ss format
     * @return this object as a String 
     */
    public String toString();

    /**
     * Add the given time record to this one
     * @param other the time record to be added to this one
     * @return the sum of this time record and the other
     */
    public Time add(Time other);

}

//my attempt
public class TimeB implements Time {

//  private int hours;
//  private int minutes;
//  private int seconds;
    private int totalSeconds;

    /**
     * Simple constructor assumes data is in proper format
     * 
     * @param h - number of hours
     * @param m - number of minutes
     * @param s - number of seconds
     */
    public TimeB(int h, int m, int s) {
        totalSeconds = h;
        totalSeconds = m;
        totalSeconds = s;


    }

//formula to calculate total sum of runners
    public void addTime(TimeB other) {
        this.totalSeconds += other.totalSeconds;
        this.totalSeconds += other.totalSeconds;
        this.totalSeconds += other.totalSeconds;
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of leftover seconds (those not part of a full minute)
     * in this object
     * 
     * @return the number of seconds
     */
    public int getSeconds() {
        return totalSeconds % 60;
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of leftover minutes (those not part of a full hour) in
     * this object
     * 
     * @return the number of minutes
     */
    public int getMinutes() {
        return (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of full hours in this object
     * 
     * @return the number of hours
     */
        public int getHours() {
          return totalSeconds / 3600;
        }

    /**
     * Constructor that assumes a total number of seconds
     * 
     * @param total - the total number of seconds taken
     */
//  public TimeB(int total) {
//      hours = total / 3600;
//      minutes = (total / 60) % 60;
//      seconds = total % 60;
//  }

    public TimeB(int total) {
    totalSeconds = totalSeconds / 3600;
    totalSeconds = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60;
    totalSeconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    }
    /**
     * Adds the given time to the current time, producing the sum
     * 
     * @param other - the given time to add
     * @return the sum of this time and the other time
     */
    public Time add(Time other) {
        int remainder = 0;
        int newSec = this.totalSeconds + other.getSeconds();

        // if over a minute, carry.
        if (newSec >= 60) {
            remainder = 1;
            newSec -= 60;
        }
        this.totalSeconds = newSec;
        int newMin = this.totalSeconds + remainder + other.getMinutes();
        remainder = 0;

        // carry if over an hour
        if (newMin >= 60) {
            remainder = 1;
            newMin -= 60;
        }
        this.totalSeconds = newMin;
        this.totalSeconds += other.getHours() + remainder;

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Return a String representation of this time
     * 
     * @return this time represented as a String in hh:mm:ss format
     */
    public String toString() {
//      return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
        return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", getHours(), getMinutes(), getSeconds());
         return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }



    public int compareTo(Time other) {
        return 17;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor that initializes TimeA object in string format
     * @param t
     */
    public TimeB(String t) {
        hours = Integer.parseInt(t.substring(0,t.indexOf(':')));
        minutes = Integer.parseInt(t.substring(t.indexOf(':') + 1,t.lastIndexOf(':')));
        seconds = Integer.parseInt(t.substring(t.lastIndexOf(':') + 1,t.length()));

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you clearly specify as what are your objectives and how much have you achieved and where you are stuck that you need help?

Comment: My objective is to eliminate the 3 private instance variables hours, minutes, and seconds and instead use a single private instance variable named totalSeconds to store all the time in seconds. First I commented out the 3 variables and then added a variable named totalSeconds. Doing this will obviously effect the rest of the code because the original variables got commented out for a single variable (totalSeconds). I want the program to still produce output as it did before, but I need the output to be seconds. FYI, before it had output in the form hh:mm:ss but now I just need totalSeconds.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to refactoring, the process is usually something like this:

1. Swap old variables for new variables.
2. See what breaks.
3. Update broken code to use the new variables.
4. Repeat 2 & 3 until your code runs, and does what you want it to do!

It can be a bit daunting when you first start a refactor, but once you get started it normally works itself out. Ultimately, you've got to decide what you want the new code to look like and how you want it to perform because refactoring usually includes some change to how the code works.

---

With regards to the case in your question, here are some pointers:

**Constructors**
You can get away with just one here, which only takes `seconds` as a parameter. You could also keep the hours / mins/ seconds constructor and work out seconds from that, too. Examples below:

```
private int totalSeconds;

public TimeB(int totalSeconds) {
    this.totalSeconds = totalSeconds;
}

public TimeB(int hours, int minutes, int seconds){
    this.totalSeconds = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds;
}
```

**Getters (and setters)**
You can keep your current `getSeconds()`, `getMinutes()`, and `getHours()` methods with a tiny bit of maths. Try these:

```
public int getSeconds() {
    // Modulus to return remainder after "/ 60" (factoring out hours and mins)
    return totalSeconds % 60;
}

public int getMinutes() {
    // Divide by 60 to get to minutes (factoring out seconds), then modulus to return remainder after "/ 60" (factoring out hours)
    return (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
}

public int getHours() {
    // Divide by 60 to get to minutes (factoring out seconds), then by 60 again convert to hours
    return (totalSeconds / 60) / 60;
}
```

**Adding Two TimeBs**
This bit is easy now! You just have to get the total seconds, and not worry about carrying anything over. Assuming you have a `getTotalSeconds()` method, which returns the total seconds, the add method will look like this:

```
public Time add(Time other) {
    totalSeconds = totalSeconds + other.getTotalSeconds();

    return this;
}
```